# Liquid State Machine: How is it different to Spiking Neural Network Models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, biological-neural-network

I am very new to the 'reservoir computing world', and I've heard that the Liquid State Machines (LSM) are a certain kind of spiking neuron network models (SNN). Exactly what is the difference in terms of the implementation between the two.

Another aspect on which I need some clarity is in regards to their counterpart the 'Leaky integrator models of Echo state network (ESN).
I found from another answer in the forum that 'as I see it (I could be wrong) the big difference between the two approaches is the individual unit. In liquid state machine use biological like neurons, and in the Echo state use more analog units. So in term of “very short term memory” the Liquid State approach each individual neuron remember its own history, where in the Echo state approach each individual neuron react base only on the current state, there for the memory stored in the activity between the units.

Please tell me if this is the correct and if not what is the actual concept behind them.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, it has very little to do with programming, you are inviting a theoretical open ended discussion about a scientific and mathematical subject. Questions on Stack Overflow should ideally be short concise answerable questions concerning reproducible problems that you have encountered and can explain in your question.

Comment: Apologies for that Michael, I will post this in some other forum.
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Good luck, and please come back with your programming problems :)

Comment: @HenryKissinger Consider posting to http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It might not be the right place to post, but it helped me

Comment: @Michael Where do you suggest this question be asked then?

Answer (score 3):

Spiking neurons is a *neuron* model. LSM on the other hand is a *network* model. So LSM is part of a group of network models with spiking neurons (also called graded response or analog). ESN has the same units like a normal Perceptron and is thus part of the other (more popular) paradigm where neurons fire at each propagation cycle. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiking_neural_network) gives a simple enough introduction. The basic idea is to not consider neurons to be binary/digital (on/off) but analog by decoding the *time* between spikes  which is now thought to be main source of information transportation between neurons. Whether the human brain is actually analog or digital is unknown but there's evidence of both as well as the true mechanic being something completely different. So whether one model is *in fact* more realistic cannot really be said with certainty.

Answer (score 0):

i also new to this field , liquid state Machine: consider a pound of water what happens when you threw a pebbles in it.  A series concentric Circles are created which eventually vanish ,you can learn something about where and when those pebbles where dropped in water if you look at where ripples intersecting and in case of echo states machines the idea is similar like sound wave from echo sort of interfering with one another is similar to the way that multiple inputs would interfere with one another and they are also past instantiations interference with one another within high dimension network